# qt optimize drawing of outlined text

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I use such code to draw outlined text:

```
 painter.setPen(Qt::black);
 painter.setBrush(Qt::white);
 QPainterPath ppath;
 ppath.addText({200., 200.}, font(), line);
 painter.drawPath(ppath);
```

it works, but so slow...
For 100 captions it takes 30-50 milleseconds on 4GHz CPU,
it is too long, because I want at least 10FPS, and I need much more stuff
in addition to drawing of captions.

Any hint how speedup code bellow?
I thought that Qt has font cache,
but for some reason 50% of program spend inside `libfreetype` in `TT_RunIns` code, while I draw only digits, so I thought that it should cache all glyphs after several iterations. May be I need call some function to turn on font cache?
Note for simplicity I draw text on the same positon,
in real program of course I do it in the right way.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QWidget>
#include <algorithm>

struct MyW : public QWidget {
  void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override {
    QPainter painter{this};
    painter.fillRect(rect(), Qt::red);

    painter.setPen(Qt::black);
    painter.setBrush(Qt::white);

    QVector<QString> lines;
    lines.resize(100);
    std::generate(std::begin(lines), std::end(lines),
                  [] { return QString::number(qrand()); });

    QElapsedTimer timer;
    timer.start();
    for (const auto &line : lines) {
      QPainterPath ppath;
      ppath.addText({200., 200.}, font(), line);
      painter.drawPath(ppath);
    }
    qInfo("paint text takes %d ms", static_cast<int>(timer.elapsed()));
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MyW w;
  w.resize(600, 800);
  w.show();
  QTimer timer;
  QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, &app, [&w] { w.update(); });
  timer.start(1000);
  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: Isn't QPainterPath supposed to have all elements added and only then draw them (just like any other graphic path)?
IOW, what happens if you create the path before the loop and call draw on it after the loop?

Comment: @catalin For some reason  `QPainterPath` with many elements can become slower in not linear fashion. But in this case actually I don't see any time difference between one `QPainterPath` creation or 100 `QPainterPath`, because of the most time is spend inside `QPainterPath::drawPath` and `QPainterPath::addText`.

Comment: The time spent in `addText` could be explained by the fact that all text is transformed in a complex set of curves. The time in `drawPath` could probably be improved by disabling the outline (https://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8017-Slow-painting-in-QGraphicsView?p=43043#post43043).

Comment: Do you really have ~100 text labels that will change on each update?  If you can provide more info regarding the actual use-case then it might be easier to make suggestions.

Comment: @catalin All this stuff about outline, so I can not disable it.

Comment: @G.M. I have something like "map" (not exactly map, but similar thing) many things with captions (you can imagine it as "streets", "houses" and so on things). And user can move "map", change "scale" and so on thing. In reality I may have ~1000 captions on big enough monitor.